# How to restore a logical Volume Group with missing devices?

Tags: lvm

I have a volumegroup which consists of three harddisks and several LVs (var,tmp,root,swap).
One of the harddisks crashed recently, but i urgently need some data from LV var.
So, after rebooting the machine without the crashed disk, i run

```
vgchange -D -a y volGroup0
```

in order to activate the volumegroup and mount the logical volumes.
However, the command returns

```
Cannot activate XXX. All segments are missing
...
0 logical volume(s) in volume group "volGroup0" now active.
```

What does that mean? Is all data lost? What could be the next step in order to rescue some data?

Comment: Were you using dm-RAID at all, or just spanning multiple PVs with volGroup0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to recover the data (note that any data on the failed disk is **lost**), you'll need to replace the failed disk with a new one and rebuild the LVM. You won't be able to mount the group otherwise.

To do this, you'll need to know the failed disk's UUID by using `pvscan`. It'll say that a UUID is missing and this is what you need.

Then, when you have the new disk in the server, type: `pvcreate --uuid uidhere /dev/sdc` where "uidhere" is the UUID you got from pvscan and `/dev/sdc` is the new disk device.

Then, type `vgcfgrestore volgroupname` where volgroupname is the name given to the volume group (so `vgcfgrestore volGroup0`).

Then, type `vgscan` to recover the volume group. And finally, `vgchange -ay volGroup0` to activate the group. You'll likely need to `e2fsck` the affected partition if it's unreadable.

Reference: http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/appnote/19386.html#DiskPermanentlyRemoved